# Friendly Id with UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have project with Rails 4.1. I need to implement url something like this .../items/. I know I can make it manually, but I'm too lazy for it.

Does everybody know how can I use friendly_id to get UUID for slug?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `to_param` method in the Item model and return the UUID of the instance.

The default `to_param` method returns the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

**friendly_id**

`friendly_id` basically just replaces your `:id` parameter with a `:slug` in the [`.find` method for ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object). I think what you're asking is if you wanted to use the `:uuid` attribute for your lookups, you'll need to something like the following:

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
Class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   friendly_id :uuid, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will allow you to perform the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :your_controller #-> domain.com/your_controller/:id
```

You'll be able to pass in your `:uuid` to the `:id`, both through the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) method, and in the  `.find` method too. Apart from that, I don't see what the issue would be?

Comment: I have empty uuid using friendly_id this way

Comment: Okay well you're going to have to provide more information than that - how do you expect me to create a solution based off such scant details?

Comment: Maybe something like this https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/test/slugged_test.rb#L238-L260 I will try

Answer (score 0):

Follow standard instructions and create slug column for your model.

Add friendly_id to your model:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :uuid, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

We do not have uuid column for our model, but we can specify method which able to generate it if slug is not set yet.

```
def uuid
  slug || SecureRandom.uuid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for how to use friendly_id with a table that has uuid primary keys.

For me, I was getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PostsController#create
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = uuid LINE 1: ...type" = $1 AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = "posts".... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The solution was to rollback the migration (`rails db:rollback STEP=1`), then go into the slugs migration and change this line

```rb
t.integer  :sluggable_id,   :null => false
```

to this

```rb
t.uuid  :sluggable_id,   :null => false
```

More info [here](https://medium.com/@steve-condylios/make-descriptive-urls-using-friendly-id-34bffd3a6ed7).